# Displaying values of array

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

[after edit 1] I have seen the other answers here in SO, and from looking at my code, I find that I am adhering to the principle of Java's pass-by-value-of-reference. But still my array is not getting sorted. Please can someone point out any errors I am making in my code?

[after edit 2] Found the problem. It was nothing to do with array passing. In my merge method, it should be if (end-start<=0) not the other way round!

I am trying to implement mergesort. However, I am unable to display values of my array and am unsure of how to pass my arrays in Java such that the original array can be modified.

How can I modify my current code to display the values of the sorted array?

I [understand java passes the copy of the array's reference around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), but doesnt this mean that the original array gets modified?

CODE:

I am calling mergesort method from my main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] qn = {10,22,33,4,5,6,1};
        qn= mergesort(qn,0,qn.length-1);
        for (int i=0;i<qn.length;i++){ //print to see values if sorted/not
               System.out.print(qn[i]+ " ");
        }

    }

public static int[] mergesort(int[] arr,int start,int end){
            int mid = (end+start)/2;
        if (end - start<=0){
            return arr;
        }
            else if (end-start>=1){     
            arr=mergesort(arr,start,mid);
            arr=mergesort(arr,mid+1,end);

        }
            arr=merge(arr,start,end);
            for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                   System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            return arr;
    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] arr,int start,int end){
            int mid= (start+end)/2;
        if(start-end<=0){
            return arr;
        }

        int a= start; int b = mid+1;
        while (a<=mid && b <=end){
            if (arr[b]<arr[a]){
            int tmp = arr[b++];
                for(int i=++mid;i>a;i--){
                arr[i]=arr[i-1];
                }
            arr[a++]=tmp;
                    }
            else if (arr[b]>arr[a]){
            a++;
            }
            else{ //arr[b]=arr[a]
                if(a==mid && b == end){
                break; //all between mid and end will be equal too 
                }
                int tmp= arr[b++];
                            a++;
                for (int i=++mid;i>a;i--){
                arr[i]=arr[i-1];
                }
                arr[a++]=tmp;
                //a++;
                //b++;
            }       

            }
            return arr;
    }
    }
```

modified my answer based on Manu's below. but it's still not working. Attaching code below:

```
public static void mergesort(int[] arr,int start,int end){
        int mid = (end+start)/2;
    if (end - start<=0){
        return;
    }
        else if (end-start>=1){     
        mergesort(arr,start,mid);
        mergesort(arr,mid+1,end);

    }
        merge(arr,start,end);
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
               System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        return;
}

public static void merge(int[] arr,int start,int end){
        int mid= (start+end)/2;
    if(start-end<=0){
        return;
    }

    int a= start; int b = mid+1;
    while (a<=mid && b <=end){
        if (arr[b]<arr[a]){
        int tmp = arr[b++];
            for(int i=++mid;i>a;i--){
            arr[i]=arr[i-1];
            }
        arr[a++]=tmp;
                }
        else if (arr[b]>arr[a]){
        a++;
        }
        else{ //arr[b]=arr[a]
            if(a==mid && b == end){
            break; //all between mid and end will be equal too (pearl)
            }
            int tmp= arr[b++];
                        a++;
            for (int i=++mid;i>a;i--){
            arr[i]=arr[i-1];
            }
            arr[a++]=tmp;
            //a++;
            //b++;
        }       

        }
        return;
}
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: I've seen that. But I am unable to apply that knowledge in my code hence the question with details in the code. Maybe I should have posted that link earlier.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java

Comment: not sure how that's relevant @Raedwald

Comment: @stretchr, both links posted by Raedwald answer this question perfectly. I believe this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Husman, thanks for highlighting. I'm genuinely unable to see how, can you please shed some light?

Comment: please see edit 2 above, wasn't about array passing after all.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, in Java, the **copy of the reference** of the array gets passed to the function. However, both references point to the **same object** (the array in your case). This means if you change the values of the array in your `merge`-method, the values of the array in your `mergesort`-method changes too. Reqrite your code to this:

```
 public static void mergesort(int[] arr, ...
 public static void merge(int[] arr, ...
```

and simply call

```
 merge(arr, start, mid);
```

Comment: I did that (note you can't call non-static from static method). But it still doesn't work

Comment: What does not work? Is the entire array still the same?

Comment: Yes, the output does not change

Comment: Your merge-method does something wrong...

Comment: yes you're right @Manu. Please see edit 2 above.